# Using single pipeline for multiple application

Tags: azure-devops

I was created one pipeline.yml for .NET project.
I have 10 .NET applications in 10 different repositories.

How can I reusable this .yml file for all .NET applications without checkout this yml file into respective repos.

How can I do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question and you have 10 .Net applications on 10 separate repositories, maybe you could try to use [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) to share common used stuff (like yaml template... see below)

According to my experience, use a [yaml template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) where you can write reusable content with your own defined parameters. You will necessarily need one short .yml for each project that use your template. But the .yml content will be really short and you won't have to change it every time.

Hope i has helpfull.

Comment: Thank you Orkad for your help.
From the above solution, if I want to make any changes in my yml, I need to edit it in each and every project manually. I'm I correct?

Comment: you'r welcome ! Yes you are correct. For every projects your yaml files must reference the yaml template with project relative parameters (like project name, ...)